# How to calculate a date difference in twig?

Tags: views, theming

I am using date range field in views and would like to display dates in the format
  `5-May +3 days` using twig. Te values that can be used as per drupal are:
`{{ field_mycontent_dates__value }} == Raw value 
{{ field_mycontent_dates__end_value }} == Raw end_value`

How can I make the calculation and display it using rewrite output option in views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a pre-processor as @Kevin suggested:

**cargaview.info.yml**

```
       name: cargaview
    type: module
    description: modifies carga node fields
    core: 8.x
    package: Flete
    dependencies:
      - field
enter code here
```

---

**src/Plugin/Field/FieldFormatter/CargaViewFormatter.php**

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\cargaview\Plugin\Field\FieldFormatter;

use Drupal\Core\Field\FormatterBase;
use Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemListInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Datetime\DrupalDateTime;

/**
 * Plugin implementation of the 'carga_view' formatter.
 *
 * @FieldFormatter(
 *   id = "carga_view",
 *   label = @Translation("Carga View"),
 *   field_types = {
 *     "daterange"
 *   }
 * )
 */
class CargaViewFormatter extends FormatterBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function defaultSettings() {
    return [
      'separator' => '+',
    ] + parent::defaultSettings();
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function viewElements(FieldItemListInterface $items, $langcode) {
    $elements = [];
    $separator = $this->getSetting('separator');

    foreach ($items as $delta => $item) {
      if (!empty($item->start_date) && !empty($item->end_date)) {
        /** @var \Drupal\Core\Datetime\DrupalDateTime $start_date */
        $start_date = $item->start_date;
        /** @var \Drupal\Core\Datetime\DrupalDateTime $end_date */
        $end_date = $item->end_date;

        if ($start_date->getTimestamp() !== $end_date->getTimestamp()) {

          $date_diff = $end_date->getTimestamp() - $start_date->getTimestamp();
          $day_diff = floor($date_diff / (60 * 60 * 24));

          $elements[$delta] = [
            '#type' => 'markup',
            '#markup' => date('d-M-Y', $start_date->getTimestamp()) . ' ' . $separator . ' ' . $day_diff . 'd',
          ];
        }
        else {
          $elements[$delta] = [
            '#type' => 'markup',
            '#markup' => date('d-M-Y', $start_date->getTimestamp()),
          ];

          if (!empty($item->_attributes)) {
            $elements[$delta]['#attributes'] += $item->_attributes;
            // Unset field item attributes since they have been included in the
            // formatter output and should not be rendered in the field template.
            unset($item->_attributes);
          }
        }
      }
    }

    return $elements;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for? There is good info here to pass the cred... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15657687/twig-date-difference

Top answer:

```
{# endDate and startDate are strings or DateTime objects #}
{% set difference = date(endDate).diff(date(startDate)) %}
{% set leftDays = difference.days %}
{% if leftDays == 1 %}
  1 day
{% else %}
  {{ leftDays }} days
{% endif %}
```

Another tidbit from same question:

```
{{ entity.ending_date|time_diff(entity.starting_date) }}
```

If not let us know. Plus depending on how you have configured Drupal to render out the value of the {{ field_mycontent_dates__value }} field, it may be as simple as something like:

```
{% set time = value_1 - value_2 %} then {{ time | date('F j i') }}
```

Ultimately, what you're looking for I believe are "twig filters".

Comment: Wouldn’t it just be easier to preprocess this data and send it into the template?

Comment: Unfortunately, none of these answers work.  I will give it a try using @Kevin suggestion.