# Comparing node creation and modification dates in twig

Tags: 8, theming

I want to compare a node's creation date and modified date in Twig, and it drives me bonkers. I've looked at various examples and snippets as part of [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/251191/how-to-calculate-a-date-difference-in-twig), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15657687/twig-date-difference), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318914/how-to-render-a-datetime-object-in-a-twig-template) or [this external source](http://qpleple.com/compare-dates-with-twig/).

Using Drupal 8, Bootstrap 3, Bootstrap Layouts, Display Suite, and a custom  sub-theme, I have a twig template customising what is going to be displayed and how. This custom template is a copy of the default bootstrap layouts 1 column template.

Within the template, I can access and print the dates using this:

```
{{ main.content.node_changed_date }}
{{ main.content.node_post_date }}
```

and all is well.

However, I want to compare the dates in my template like so:

```
{% if main.content.node_post_date|date('Y-m-d') > main.content.node_changed_date|date('Y-m-d') %}
    {{ main.content.node_post_date }}
{% endif %}
```

But this barks at me with the following error:

```
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
TypeError: DateTime::__construct() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in DateTime->__construct() (line 455 of /home/michel/devel/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Extension/Core.php).

DateTime->__construct(Array, Object) (Line: 455)
twig_date_converter(Object, Array, Object) (Line: 380)
twig_date_format_filter(Object, Array, 'Y-m-d') (Line: 77)
```

Yes, I use Composer to manage my installation.

What am I doing wrong?

*Pulling my hairs*

Michel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't compare render arrays. To compare fields better use raw values stored in the node:

```
{% if node.getCreatedTime > node.getChangedTime %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```

(The comparison doesn't make much sense, probably you want to swap both dates)

The `node` object is available in node and page templates. In other templates you might find it in a deeper level. If not and the node is displayed as main content you can add it in preprocess:

```
  if ($node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')) {
    $variables['node'] = $node;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I would need to dig deeper, but my Drupal knowledge is too limited. It is part of a view output that lists the 5 most recent notes of a given type, and displays them in a custom display mode.

Comment: Then you could use the node template `node--content-type--custom-display-mode.html.twig`.

Comment: I need to use a copy of a bootstrap-layout template, as I am making use of a display suite dynamic token field to display the number of comments (is there another way to do that?)

Comment: In a node template `{{ node.comment.comment_count }}`

Comment: Perfect, it works like a charm! - Out of curiosity, does Drupal know a third date, the publication date? Because sometimes it takes longer than a day to create a content node, and in that case a publication date (or the most recent one, in case of repeated publication and unpublication) would be more meaningful than the technical node creation date.