# node.getRevisionCreationTime equivalent in views

Tags: views, 8, nodes

This question is somewhat related to [Comparing node creation and modification dates in twig](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/263100/comparing-node-creation-and-modification-dates-in-twig) I asked earlier.

For the website in question, we agreed to the following semantics of the various dates related to a node (in our case, blog posts):

- **Creation date**: The date the note was created.
- **Changed date**: The date when any of the node's modifiable settings were changed.
- **First publication**: The date the node was first published (using Drupal module [Publication Date](https://www.drupal.org/project/publication_date)).
- **Publication date**: The date a new revision of the node has been created - in other words, the *current revision's date*.

In rendering the content, all is well when using `node.getRevisionCreationTime` for the publication date in the relevant twig templates and display modes.

However, I what certain blocks and views to order the blog posts by publication date as defined above.

I fail to find the right settings when defining the view - I find the Views user interface incredibly complicated and not intuitive at all. In my (perhaps naive) assumption, using the Content Revision field `Changed` or `Authored on` as sufficient, but I suspect that that doesn't always relates to the *current* revision.

See the attached screenshot on how I have defined the view:[image: The view]

**UPDATE: An example:**

The above view (with some filtering on example name) gives the following result:
[image: View result]

Taking a screenshot when editing the node I get this:
[image: Node creation, publication and last saved/changed times]

So far, so good: Node creation, publication and changed times all match. But look at the "Revision created" and "Revision changed" dates - they match the corresponding node times!

Checking the node's revisions, I see that the current revision's date (which date exactly? Created? Changed? Something else?) is 12 June 2018 - but nowhere to be found in my view - see screenshot:
[image]

The revision date 12 June 2018 is the date I want to fetch as the "Publication date" explained above.

How do I do that in a view?

Please help!

TIA,
Michel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer eventually:

The crucial thing to do was to built the query starting with content revisions rather content. Rather unintuitively - creating a relationship the other way around does NOT get you to where you need to get in this situation!

To create a view listing the node's title, creation date, changed date, first publication, and publication date (the creation date of the *current* revision, follow these steps, and then add/remove as required:

1. **Create a view showing** content revisions of type all as follows, creating a page for easier review:
   [image: A view showing content revisions]
2. **Remove the field** "Content revision: Changed (Changed)" as this is not what we are interested in.
3. **Add a relationship** to Content as seen in the screenshot below:
   [image: Beware the lack of documentation!]
   This is one of the #DrupalWTF moments - where's the crucial documentation that allows me to select the correct relationship!?
   There are apparently two RDBMS foreign key relationships you can use to join revisions and content:

   a. Via content revision foreign key to the id of the node this revision belongs to - this is the *first* content relationship, and

   b. Via revision id referenced as foreign key from the content table as current node - this is the *second* content relationship shown above in the screenshot.

For whatever reason you **cannot** reach the creation date of a revision when joining via the first content relationship, #Drupal, #WTF?

Require the relationship for all results, and change the administrative title if you wish:
[image: The relationship needs to be present]

4. **Add a filter criterion to show only blog posts**
   The relationship shows revisions for all content types, so we need to filter for content type blog post (Yours may be different). This is pretty straightforward, see the following screenshots:

   a. Select the filter criterion:
   [image]

   b. Configure the filter:
   [image]
5. **Add the various date related fields**
   This is repetitive; to add the fields select them all in the "Add field" form, and configure them all the same way:

   - (Content) Authored on,
   - (Content) Changed,
   - (Content) Published on,
   - (Content revision) Revision create time

Here are the screenshots:
[image]
and
[image]

Et voila, all fields present as required.

Now you (I) can go to town for formatting and sorting.